# How to Read JSON data from server in JSP page in Struts 2 project?

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, struts2

I'm not getting JSON data in my `module` Select Box upon selecting course name from `Course` Select Box.

My code is able to hit the Action class server side, my only problem is how to read `modulelist` field in `module` select box.

**struts.xml**

```xml
    <package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
        <action name="ajaxAction" class="com.admin.AddTestAction">             
            <result type="json" />
        </action>       
    </package>
```

**Struts2 Action class:**

```java
        package com.admin;
        
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        
        import com.db.DAO;
        import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
        import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
        
        public class AddTestAction extends ActionSupport {
        
            List<String>courselist= new ArrayList<String>();        
            List<String>modulelist= new ArrayList<String>();        
            String courseName;
            String module;
            
            public String execute()
            {           
                System.out.print("execute method called from TestAction");          
                DAO dao= new DAO();             
                courselist=dao.getCourses();    
                modulelist.add("select module");        
                if(getCourseName()!=null) {
                    System.out.print("course name is:"+getCourseName());                
                    int id=dao.getCourseId(getCourseName());                
                    modulelist=dao.getModules(id);              
                    for(int i=0;i<modulelist.size();i++) {          
                        System.out.println(modulelist.get(i));    
                    }           
                }           
                return SUCCESS;                     
            }
        
            public List<String> getCourselist() {
                return courselist;
            }
        
            public void setCourselist(List<String> courselist) {
                this.courselist = courselist;
            }
        
            public String getCourseName() {
                return courseName;
            }
        
            public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
                this.courseName = courseName;
            }
        
            public List<String> getModulelist() {
                return modulelist;
            }
        
            public void setModulelist(List<String> modulelist) {
                this.modulelist = modulelist;
            }
        
            public String getModule() {
                return module;
            }
        
            public void setModule(String module) {
                this.module = module;
            }
        
        }
```

**addTest.jsp:**

```html
        <html>    
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                <title>Insert title here</title>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function loadmodule() {
                        alert("Handler for Select Course called.");    
                        var course = $("#course").val();    
                        $.getJSON('ajaxAction', {    
                            courseName: course
                        },    
                        function(jsonResponse) {    
                            var select = $('#module');    
                            select.find('option').remove();    
                            $.each(jsonResponse.stateMap, function(key, value) {    
                                $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo(select);    
                            });        
                        });
                    }
                </script>
            </head>        
            <body>
                <s:select name="course" id="course" list="courselist" headerValue="--select course--" headerKey="-1" label="Choose Course" onchange="loadmodule();"></s:select>
                <s:select name="module" id="module" list="modulelist" label="choose module"></s:select>
            </body>
        <html>
```

Comment: What's returned in `jsonResponse`?

Comment: Actually Not getting anything in module select box. check my stack trace.

Comment: You're missing the dependency shown in the stack trace.

Comment: This is `commons-lang3-3.3.1.jar`.

Comment: -1 for having removed the formatting, good job.

Comment: @RomanC thank you sir. no error in stack trace . but please help me to fetch json data from server back to my jsp page.It would be very helpful. Please.

Comment: @user3622530 This is pure javascript/jquery if you got json object in the callback. Might be you reference other property because the code is like from one of my answers.

Comment: @user3622530 Please make sure you look at your question after you edit it; the *entire* question was in a code block. Only code should be in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `json` response you should iterate a list, not a map. If you are using a list to populate drop-down the option text is usually the same as its value.

```
$.each(jsonResponse.modulelist, function(idx, value) {    
    $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);    
});
```